# Testing React Native code without an Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I'm a uni student who has to create a React Native mobile application for an assignment. Initially, we were using University computers for our coding and using Android Studio emulators to test our code once it was written to make sure it works on an android device.

Unfortunately due to the current epidemic, my University has closed all facilities including their 24 hour library which myself and coursemates were using to complete this assignment. This means that all of our assignment work must now be completed on personal computers. My personal laptop doesn't seem to work well with Android Studio, I am assuming it is due to the ageing hardware. I cannot get an emulator to run.

I would like to know if there is a way to use an online emulator or something of the sort to test the code I have written to make sure it actually works. I am aware of expo but since I am using the React Native CLI I don't think I am able to use Expo for an emulator. Is there a way that I can still use the Expo emulator even though this React project is not using Expo CLI?

Unfortunately I also cannot use a personal device as I do not own an Android phone.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have made my course tutors aware of my circumstances and was informed that I can apply for exceptional factors to be taken into consideration when marking my work. However I would much rather complete the work to the best of my ability if possible without needing to apply for the above.

Comment: So you don't have an android device or laptop that runs android emulator? You cannot run your app without these 2 things. You could try connecting to a machine remotely, but you effectively have to have a machine reserved for you with this capability, and that won't be cheap.

You could try to understand why android studio is not performing so well, and improve that?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know is the genymotion, it should be a bit easier to run on less powerful hardware but take no word from me because I've never used it. Otherwise if you know someone with a more powerful pc/laptop you can clone your project from git to that pc, connect to that pc with teamviewer or remote desktop (vpn needed) and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution at last after making a build for you app you can try running the app on [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) a cloud testing platform. But it's gonna be tough if you have a bug or something. Or you can use Genymotion it runs on a less powerful hardware